# Doubt in solved example - solution of integral equation

Tags: fourier-transform, integral-equations

I am attaching a solved example for integral equation...I have not understood the underlined step ("comparing the above equation with given equation..."). Would be grateful for a little detailed explaination[image]

Comment: After thinking about it, to me there appear to be 3 printing mistakes as follows:

Comment: 1. Instead of x=a, read x=$\alpha$, instead of $\frac{\pi}{2}$g(a), read $\frac{\pi}{2}$g(x), and instead of f(x)=A(x) in the bottom line read f(x)=A($\alpha$).   Would be grateful somebody can verfiy these typos in the textbook.

Comment: But that does not  explain the e$^{-x}$ in the subsequent integrals. Request help to understand